# @ngrx - linking store query to BehaviorSubject

Tags: javascript, redux, observable, ngrx

I've got LOTS of Reducer Queries that I need to Link up to behavior subjects.  At the moment I'm doing this, for every single one!

Is there a more concise way to express this?

```
this._higherCurveObservable = this.store.let(getCurveSummaryForInstrumentTimeframe(this._instrument, this._timeframe.Code));
this._higherCurveSubject = <BehaviorSubject<CurveSummary>>new BehaviorSubject(null).distinctUntilChanged();
this._higherCurveSubscription = this._higherCurveObservable.subscribe(x => this._higherCurveSubject.next(x));
this._higherCurveSubject.subscribe(x => this.higherCurveChange(x));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no need to create seperate `BehaviourSubjects`, you could just base your required `Observables` on the store-stream.

(The only time when you would need something like this - and I'm not assuming you did this - would be the case when you are trying to abuse a `BehaviourSubject` to be able to take data from the store as well as to dispatch data *from the side*, in which case you should rethink the architecture, since this would go against the concepts of `ngrx` of having a single central store.)

So there are multiple ways to write this with less overhead.

---

**Example 1**: A perpetual subscription, that never unsubscribes (e.g. in a Service)

```
this.store
    .let(getCurveSummaryForInstrumentTimeframe(this._instrument, this._timeframe.Code))
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .do(x => this.higherCurveChange(x))
    .subscribe();
```

---

**Example 2**: A temporary subscriptions, that should unsubscribe at a specific point in time (e.g. in a Component, it should unsubscribe when the Component is destroyed)

```
const higherCurve$: Observable<CurveSummary> = this.store
    .let(getCurveSummaryForInstrumentTimeframe(this._instrument, this._timeframe.Code))
    .distinctUntilChanged();
this._higherCurveSubscription = higherCurve$.subscribe(x => this.higherCurveChange(x));

// ... some time later
this._higherCurveSubscription.unsubscribe();
```

Comment: Very helpful! Thank you!  You are right, I was abusing behaviour subject.  I now have a single central store of data and it is working just beautifully!